# unable to call function from jquery document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function where i am setting a cookie value, when users click a button.

On change event ,I am calling two methods from my select box. This function is calling correctly and working fine.But i have problem when i am calling these two function from my below jquery function.
      `<select NAME="the_menu" size="1" id="Item" onChange="UpdateUnitMenu(this, document.form_A.unit_menu); UpdateUnitMenu(this, document.form_B.unit_menu)">`
Same method i want to call if any cookie exists in the name of "language". 
The two function basically populates another two drop-down select-box values based on the selection of the first value.

MyForm

```
 <form name="property_form" >
     <select NAME="the_menu" size="1" id="Item" onChange="UpdateUnitMenu(this, document.form_A.unit_menu); UpdateUnitMenu(this, document.form_B.unit_menu)">   <optgroup label="Select Any One Type">   </optgroup>  </select>
     <input type="button" id='continue' value="Save as default value"/>
 </form>
```

My function

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('#continue').click(function() {
                 var singleValues = $("#Item").val(); 
                $.cookie("language", singleValues); 
            })  
      alert($.cookie('language'));
      $('#Item').val($.cookie('language')).attr('selected', true);

      if($.cookie('language')!=null)
               {  
                 var th=$.cookie('language');
                 UpdateUnitMenu(th, document.form_A.unit_menu);//trying to call first function
                 UpdateUnitMenu(th, document.form_B.unit_menu);//trying to call first function
               } 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Error would suggest a problem with either document.form_A or document.form_B. Looking at the source, you don't have anything contained within those forms

Comment: @Beast-a-tron  In console getting error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unit_menu' of undefined `  . How to solve this

Comment: unit_menu doesn't exist in those forms, which is why you are getting that error. what is your html markup for those forms supposed to be?

Comment: `propMenu` is a string I think, why are you trying to get its `selectedIndex` property

Comment: you also have an error because you have to include `jquery.selectbox-0.5.` after you include **jQuery**

Comment: UpdateUnitMenu(this,document.form_A.unit_menu,document.form_B.unit_menu);u try this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function with an element reference in one case, and a string in another case.

To make the function work with both, only get the value from the `select` if it's not already a string:

```
if (typeof propMenu != 'string') {
  i = propMenu.selectedIndex;
} else {
  i = propMenu;
}
```

Alternatively, make two different functions that take different parameters, and make one function get the value from the `select` and then call the other function.

Comment: I updated My code above as you suggested. But still i have the same problem. Please help me

Comment: If you update the code in the page that I can see, that would be helpful. Right now you are the only one who can see what's happening in the code that you have locally.

Comment: I added my updated code above. Please check it above code,i named  as  update - full code(little scrolling down).  You can copy this code & save it as index.html, run this index.html to see output.

Comment: If I take the full code above, add a `$.cookie` function that simply returns a string (as I don't have the plugin locally, or the cookie) and reintroduce the code that checks the cookie and calls the function, it works.

Comment: @Ashutosh: Because you have removed the code that checks the cookie and calls the function.

Comment: I updated my code above and uploaded it here to show output-> http://www.ansoftsys.com/apps/resources/unitconv/new.html   But still i have the same problem.  i.e two selectbox is not populating based on the value of the first selectbox

Comment: @Ashutosh: Aha, you are storing a different value in the cookie from what you are using in the function. As you are selecting the item in the dropdown, you can pick up the index from there: `var th = $('#Item').get(0).selectedIndex.toString();`